# How to write on a new line in a text file using PHP?

Tags: php, file, text, line

I am trying to write in a text file using PHP. Every `$result` string must be on a new line in the txt file but when I am typing this all `$result` string is on the same line. What is the problem ?

Here is my code:

```
$result=date("Y.m.d").'!'.$_POST['name'].'!'.$_POST['price'].'!'.$selectedGroup."\n";
file_put_contents('data.txt', $result,FILE_APPEND)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `PHP_EOL` predefined constant:

```
file_put_contents('data.txt', $result . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

From [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php):

> **PHP_EOL (string)**
>
> The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform.
>
> Available since PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.2

To test your input, you may try to output your file data with [`file()`](http://php.net/file) (it should properly determine line separations):

```
print_r(file('data.txt'));
```

If it contains more than one element, then your rows are separated.

Comment: His problem, I believe, lies in his verification of the result, not in actual generation of it.

Comment: It's working but It's making an empty line on the first line of the file. How to avoid that ?

Comment: @Montoolivo It might be already existing "new line symbol". This code should not produce pre-line separators. If you can, try to test it on newly created file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your editor (windows notepad?) doesn't treat `\n` as a new line.

There there kind of new lines

```
windows: \r\n

linux/unix: \n

mac: \r
```

Comment: @Montoolivo Then there should be option to set the newline type.

Answer (score 1):

How are you verifying the result? Are you opening up the file in an editor? If you are doing this on Windows, note that certain editors will show "\r\n" as a new line, while treating "\n" as a space or simply ignoring it.

Comment: You need to know who is the target audience of your generated file. You might need to have Unix version "\n", instead of the windows version of newline.